# Using Python codecs but still getting UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python-2.7, encoding

I have a non-English list of rows where each row is a list of strings and ints. I need to write this data to a file and convert all numbers to strings accordingly. 
The data contents is the following:

```
[[u'12', u'as', u'ss', u'ge', u'ge', u'm\xfcnze', u'10.0', u'25.2', u'68.05', 1, 2, 0],
[u'13', u'aas', u'sss', u'tge', u'a', u'mat', u'11.0', u'35.7', u'10.1', 1, 1, 1], ...]
```

The loop breaks on the first list which contains `u'm\xfcnze'`.

```
import codecs

with codecs.open("temp.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for row in data:
        f.write(' '.join([str(r) for r in row]))
        f.write('\n')
```

The code above fails with `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)` error.

Trying `r.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(r, str)` does not solve this issue, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `data`? I would like to know `data` type and structure to be able to help you.

Comment: @gsi-frank I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open("temp.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for row in data:
        f.write(' '.join([unicode(r) for r in row]))
        f.write('\n')
```

I'm using the [unicode()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode) function

Note, because Python 3 string data type is string unicode, your code works fine in Python 3 without any modification (no str -> unicode needed)